# Flask REST API TypeError

Tags: api, rest, flask, post, typeerror

When i try to use on "/register" POST-body-raw {"name" : "mike", "password" : "demo"} in postman i get this bug, pls help to correct:

> line 62, in signup_user
> hashed_password = generate_password_hash(data['password'], method='sha256') TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, make_response
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
import uuid
import jwt
import datetime
from functools import wraps

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'Th1s1ss3cr3t'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///library.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True

db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Users(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    public_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    password = db.Column(db.String(50))
    admin = db.Column(db.Boolean)


class Authors(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True, nullable=False)
    book = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    country = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    booker_prize = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer)


def token_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorator(*args, **kwargs):

        token = None

        if 'x-access-tokens' in request.headers:
            token = request.headers['x-access-tokens']

        if not token:
            return jsonify({'message': 'a valid token is missing'})

        try:
            data = jwt.decode(token, app.config[SECRET_KEY])
            current_user = Users.query.filter_by(public_id=data['public_id']).first()
        except:
            return jsonify({'message': 'token is invalid'})

            return f(current_user, *args, **kwargs)

    return decorator


@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signup_user():
    data = request.get_json()

    hashed_password = generate_password_hash(data['password'], method='sha256')

    new_user = Users(public_id=str(uuid.uuid4()), name=data['name'], password=hashed_password, admin=False)
    db.session.add(new_user)
    db.session.commit()

    return jsonify({'message': 'registered successfully'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your request is missing content-type header.

Content-Type:application/json

In Postman you can set it in Headers tab. Another option is to select "raw" and "JSON (application/json)" in Body tab just above the text area.